# Calling .map() on Intersection Types

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I created type definitions for a JSON API object:

```
type CommonCurrentJob = {
    id: number,
    qty: 29,
    qty_changed: 27,
    created_at: string,
    updated_at: string
}

type Job = {
    user_id: number,
    status: 'open' | 'closed',
    location: 'string',
    history: Array<{[number]: string}>,
    note: string,
}

type JobDetails = Array<{iaj_id: number, code: number}>;

type CurrentJob = {
    inventoryJob: Job & CommonCurrentJob,
    inventoryJobDetails: JobDetails & CommonCurrentJob
}
```

In the fetch call I am performing a map on json.inventoryJobDeails:

```
 return fetch(url, {credentials: 'include'})
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then((json: CurrentJob) => {
            console.log(json);
            const location = json.inventoryJob.location;
            const ref_note = json.inventoryJob.note;
            const id = json.inventoryJob.id;
            const models = json.inventoryJobDetails.map((j) => {
                return Object.assign({}, {
                    code: j.code,
                    qty: j.qty
                })
            });
            this.setState({ currentCodes: models, location: location, ref_note: ref_note, id: id})
            return json
        })
```

The error Flow is giving me:

```
Error:(152, 32) Flow: call of method `map`. Method cannot be called on any member of intersection type intersection
```

I am new to Flow and do not understand why intersection types can't be mapped. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to have properties an array? Seems like you'd be better off reorganizing your types to use a normal array.

Comment: I am modeling the JSON object. How would I represent an array of objects? Isn't `{[string]: number}[]` the way to do it?

Comment: `JobDetails & CommonCurrentJob` is "a type that is an array" combined with "an object with properties", so it'd be an array with normal numeric indices that _also_ has properties alongside the indexes. Were you trying to say that `CommonCurrentJob` should be added to the items in the array itself?

Comment: Thanks, I see my mistake, I was trying to merge an array with an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[loganfsmyth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/785065/loganfsmyth) has solved my issue in the comments:

> `JobDetails & CommonCurrentJob` is "a type that is an array" combined
>   with "an object with properties", so it'd be an array with normal
>   numeric indices that also has properties alongside the indexes.

So I have refactored my code to create a pure object intersection:

```
type CommonCurrentJob = {
    id: number,
    qty: 29,
    qty_changed: 27,
    created_at: string,
    updated_at: string
}

type Job = {
    user_id: number,
    status: 'open' | 'closed',
    location: 'string',
    history: {[number]: string}[],
    note: string,
    id: number,
    qty: 29,
    qty_changed: 27,
    created_at: string,
    updated_at: string
} & CommonCurrentJob;

type JobDetails = {
    iaj_id: number,
    code: number,
    id: number,
    qty: 29,
    qty_changed: 27,
    created_at: string,
    updated_at: string
} & CommonCurrentJob;

type CurrentJob = {
    inventoryJob: Job,
    inventoryJobDetails: JobDetails[]
}
```